# replace fetchAll by fetch to avoid memory limit

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, fetch, fetchall

I run into a memory limit error using `fetchAll` so I'm trying to use `fetch` instead but I can't find a way to do it. Any suggestion? Where/How to use the `while` instead of `foreach` ?

here is the original code:

```
// We get all the data from the table
$Qselect = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table_to_export.''); 
$Qselect->execute(array(''));
$results = $Qselect->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Here is the problem
$countRmain = $Qselect->rowCount();

// We get the column names
$Qdescribe = $pdo->prepare('DESCRIBE '.$table_to_export.'');
$Qdescribe->execute();
$limit = $Qdescribe->rowCount()-1;      // Number of column in the table
$table_fields = $Qdescribe->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); // No problem here

foreach($table_fields as $key => $fields){
    $outputCsv .= trim($fields).';';
}

// We remove the ; at the end
$outputCsv = rtrim($outputCsv, ';');

// Data
$outputCsv .= "\n";
if($countRmain > 0){
    foreach($results as $row){
            $column = 0 ;
        foreach ($row as $key => $val){         
            if (is_null($val)){
                $outputCsv .= 'NULL;';  // If the field id empty, we add NULL
            }
            else {
                $outputCsv .= $val.';'; // We add the value in the file
            }
            if ($column == $limit)
                $outputCsv .= "\n";
            $column ++;
        }
    }
}
    else
        exit('No data to export');
```

I tried to include the `foreach` loop into `while($results = $Qselect->fetch()){` but that takes a really long time (10min for 50000 rows)

PS: If I increase the PHP memory_limit it works with fetchAll but I don't want this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
1. comment line 4
2. Replace line 23:
    while($row = $Qselect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
3. Skip (or Replace) checks on line 22
```

Idea is simple: u got `$result` earlier, but not loading whole array. You just step-by-step loading records. That cant be slow enough even for 1M rows becouse u replace one piece of code iterations loop for another **same** code iterations.
If u still got time problems, try reorganize\optimize your code.

Answer (score -2):

I have also encounter this problem.

Increase the following variables so that your page execution will not stop:

```
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
```

or you can use

```
while($row = $Qselect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

in place of fatchAll

Comment: @remyremy. Its your choice, you can select any of choice. Either increase variable or use fetch as describe above. But you need to optimize code also while using fetch.

Comment: More people use this from their own wamp server so I do not want to choose this solution in the long term. I didn't vote down but I guess someone did it because in my original message I mentioned I don't want to change the memorylimit. Thanks anyway. I will try StasGrin answer soon and optimize code.